# how to get multiple ID product cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two product in my cart. and I want to display the ID in the form of an array, I have tried but the result :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [idp] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [idp] => 9 ) )
```

i want the result :

```
array(11,9)
```

my controller :

```
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items):
                        $data_product_stock[] = array(
                            'idp'   => $items['id'],
                        );
                    endforeach;
                    print_r($data_product_stock);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create array like this

```
 foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items):
                            $data_product_stock[] =  $items['id'];
                        endforeach;
                        print_r($data_product_stock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
array_column($data_product_stock, 'idp');
```

It will give array of `ids` but remember `$data_product_stock` should be array